# Why can't individual System.Array elements be accessed via index in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

Take the following example:

```
class MyArray {
    private Array _array;

    public MyArray(Array array) {
        _array = array;
    }

    public object this[int index] {
        get { return _array[index]; }
        set { _array[index]=value; }
    }
 }
```

This returns the compile error "can't access the private indexer 'this' here"

However, this functions fine if _array is declared as object[].

Does this have to do with the differences between arrays of values and references?

Comment: The Array object has an unpredictable number of dimensions, no way for the compiler to check that your index expression is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not meant to use `Array`:

> The Array class is the base class for language implementations that support arrays. However, only the system and compilers can derive explicitly from the Array class. Users should employ the array constructs provided by the language.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the description of class Array:

> Provides methods for creating, manipulating, searching, and sorting
>   arrays, thereby serving as the base class for all arrays in the common
>   language runtime.

The class does not have an indexer. If you are working on array, you can use object[] instead or using List<>